# Computing a random subset of permutations in Matlab to avoid memory errors

Tags: matlab, random, permutation

I’m trying to compute all permutations of 12 or 13 specific values (e.g., x = [73 78 84 82 79 68 85 67 84 73 79 78]), but I’m running into memory errors in Matlab (12 = 46.0 GB and 13 = 647.6 GB of memory).

Is there an easy way to select a random subset of, say, 4 million of these permutations?

Comment: Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffle https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27076-shuffle

Comment: See: [randperm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html)